# No sound in bluetooth headset when OS access its microphone (Win 10)

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headset

It used to work properly until recently, but now I can't make calls over Skype or Viber. When a call starts all audio on my end disables (but the interlocutor does hear my mic).

Audio also turns off when I open audio & video settings in Skype, or the tab "Recording" in the sound settings of the Control Panel.

I tried restarting and reconnecting the headset, disabling and re-enabling Bluetooth, checked off "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device" on both headphones and the microphone, and it didn't work.

I haven't installed any specific drivers, the system automatically recognized the headset when I first connected it. And doesn't look like this headset even got any.

I also tried launching the troubleshooter and it did not identify any problems, only offered to disable audio enhancements, which I did.

Comment: Is your headset selected as the default audio device when connected?

Comment: Yes. In playback my headset is displayed as two options: Headphones (stereo, default) and Headset ("hands-free", very low quality). In recording it's presented only as Headset, and I'm not sure whether or not this is how used to be before the problem. The thing is if I make hands-free the default playback device then I do have a fully working headset, but with unbearable sound. Also speakers do not lose sound if I just disable the headset in recording and/or use another mic. So it does look like some driver glitch to me actually...

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be that Windows 10 is treating the headphones as a Bluetooth low energy device. To fix:

1. Unpair your headphones from the computer
2. Right-click the Start menu and open Device Manager
3. Expand Bluetooth
4. Right-click Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator and disable
5. Pair your headphones
6. Enjoy

Comment: Thanks but disabling Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator doesn't seem to be doing anything for me, the issue with audio is still there...

Comment: This seems to work because it forces the low quality "headset" mode instead of head phones, which doesn't even have stereo support. Useless for, say, gaming or music production.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this same issue as far as I can tell it has to do with the Bluetooth adapter not being able to send and receive at the same time. It can only do one or the other.  So when you are in your Audio settings in skype or the recording tab in sounds, it starts to use your mic and thus disables your speaker part of your headphones.  as soon as it stops using the mic i.e. you get out of the recording tab or the settings nothing is using the mic anymore thus sound returns to your speakers.

Looking into possible fixes I have tried a lot to no success like the ones listed already.  The one thing that I found that could potentially fix the issues is upgrading to bluetooth 5.0  it has double the bandwidth of earlier versions.  With the more bandwidth it may allow it to transmit and receive simultaneously.

Just my thoughts.

Comment: It's been a while now but I'm pretty sure my headset used to work with the same adapter as expected. I did a few calls and remember the audio quality wasn't there compared to my wired mic that I began using later, but it worked. Nothing changed about my computer other than probably Windows updates, so I'm kind of leaning towards that direction in terms of what's the problem. Might be able to test the headset and the adapter on a Windows 7 machine soon so will do that...

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following method will work:

Open *Device Manager* from your search bar, scan for hardware changes. Then in *Audio inputs and outputs* section, look for the driver software for your headphone. Then check for updates.

If this doesn't work, disable the driver then enable it. If you still having audio related issues, uninstall and then reinstall the driver.

If it's the Bluetooth adapter, try connecting other Bluetooth devices to check if it works correctly. If not, please follow the same process with the Bluetooth adapter. It's `Device Manager > Bluetooth > Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)` for my laptop. For your device, it may or may not be the same.

Comment: It doesn't look like I'm able to uninstall drivers from within Device Manager... Each element has only three options: update driver, disable device and uninstall device. I tried disabling and uninstalling the headphones, and that didn't do anything, they just reappear with the same problem next time I re-connect the headphones... And there are no updates.

Comment: Are you sure that its not a hardware defect?

Comment: The headset is working properly with my phone so it's probably OK, maybe there's something wrong with PC's bluetooth adapter then, but I doubt it honestly

Comment: Try to connect other bluetooth devices to check it. See if other bluetooth headphones connect.

Answer (score -1):

Windows needs to point to the hands free version if you want to hear any audio outside of the mic/speaker connection. Bluetooth needs to know that the connection should be split. Hands-Free AG audio splits your Stereo sound into 2 mono channels.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).