# How can I listen to the Bose QC35 II headphones while using its microphone when connected to Windows 10 via Bluetooth?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, microphone, bose

My Bose QC35 II headphones are connected to Windows 10 via Bluetooth:

[image]

I'd like to use it to make a phone call in Chrome on https://voice.google.com/. However,
when I turn on the microphone, it turns off the voice of my interlocutor (i.e., I can't hear anything in the headphones).

How can I listen to the Bose QC35 II headphones while using its microphone when connected to Windows 10 via Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread may answer your question: [No sound in bluetooth headset when OS access its microphone (Win 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1496149/no-sound-in-bluetooth-headset-when-os-access-its-microphone-win-10?rq=1)

If your problem is still unresolved after trying everything mentioned in that thread, try restarting your computer. If that doesn't work, try forgetting the bluetooth connection,restarting your computer, and repairing your headphones to your computer.

You might also try opening sound settings and verifying that Bose QC35 II AG is your default communication device.

I know from personal experience that these headphones are capable of doing exactly what you describe,but my bluetooth card is almost certainly different from yours. Our Windows 10 distributions are also almost certainly dissimilar.